# Image Classifier Always Giving Same Results: Out of Ideas

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, image-recognition

I'm currently developing a CNN to predict image classification between two classes: Weapons, and not Weapons. The purpose of this project is to be able to detect whether or not a weapon (handgun/rifle) is present in an image.

My issue: No matter what I try, the classifier predicts that there is no weapon in the image. Can you guys find a flaw in my code that might be causing this issue?

I am senior Computer Science Student, but I have very little background the realm of Machine Learning.

Any help is appreciated!

```
# Initializing the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), activation='relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/chill/PycharmProjects/499Actual/venv/data/TrainDataSet/',
                                                 target_size=(64, 64),
                                                 batch_size=29,
                                                 class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/chill/PycharmProjects/499Actual/venv/data/TestDataSet/',
                                            target_size=(64, 64),
                                            batch_size=7,
                                            class_mode='binary')

valid_set = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/chill/PycharmProjects/499Actual/venv/data/ValidationDataSet/',
                                              target_size=(64, 64),
                                              batch_size=7,
                                              class_mode='binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch=348,
                         epochs=1,
                         validation_data=valid_set,
                         validation_steps=100)

# Part 3 - Making new predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

# test_image = image.load_img('C:/Users/chill/PycharmProjects/499Actual/venv/data/TestDataSet/ProbablySoap/P1030135.jpg',
#                         target_size=(64, 64))
test_image = image.load_img('C:/Users/chill/PycharmProjects/499Actual/venv/data/TestDataSet/Guns/301.jpeg',
                            target_size=(64, 64))

test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)

test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
result = classifier.predict_classes(test_image)
print(result[0][0])
var = training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
    prediction = 1
    print("Gun!")
else:
    prediction = 0
    print("Not.")
```

Disclaimer: "ProbablySoap" is just the set of images that do not contain weapons.

**UPDATE**

The input image in this scenario is an image containing a weapon. 
The output predicts "Not." every time.

**UPDATE 2**
Here is the output of the code:

```
Found 348 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 42 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 42 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/1

  1/348 [..............................] - ETA: 1:15 - loss: 0.6915 - accuracy: 0.5517
  2/348 [..............................] - ETA: 47s - loss: 0.6994 - accuracy: 0.6724 
  3/348 [..............................] - ETA: 38s - loss: 0.7130 - accuracy: 0.6897
  4/348 [..............................] - ETA: 33s - loss: 0.6565 - accuracy: 0.7155
  5/348 [..............................] - ETA: 30s - loss: 0.6496 - accuracy: 0.7103
  6/348 [..............................] - ETA: 28s - loss: 0.6384 - accuracy: 0.7241
  7/348 [..............................] - ETA: 27s - loss: 0.6301 - accuracy: 0.7340
```

...

```
346/348 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0940 - accuracy: 0.9628
347/348 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0937 - accuracy: 0.9629
348/348 [==============================] - 34s 98ms/step - loss: 0.0935 - accuracy: 0.9630 - val_loss: 0.2081 - val_accuracy: 0.9757
0
Not.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please provide the output of the code. What is the accuracy?

Comment: Can you post your training accuracy and loss? Also maybe say a little more about your training data (e.g. how many total samples, how many positive/negative samples). You're only training 1 epoch on seemingly 384 samples, I doubt you will get very good performance on such limited training, especially on image data.

Comment: @adamconkey I updated to show you the output of the code. I know that 1 epoch definitely is not enough; however, I ran it with 25 epochs multiple times and the same thing happens. The only difference is the accuracy eventually climbs to 100% and then fluctuates between 0.9600 and 1.

Comment: @Igna I updated the code to provide you with the output

Comment: Have you tried overfitting on 2 images, 1 containing a gun and 1 not, and then using your method to infer on the image containing a gun and seeing if it says the right thing?

Comment: @ConnerHill that's good at least it's training, so it seems it's just the prediction is bad. Two things: 1) What does `result` look like when you print it? I'm a little confused why you have to index it `result[0][0]` to get at the value. 2) You can try prediction on a training image when you have a model that was predicting at 100% on the training set. If it still gives you bogus predictions then you know it's just in the way you are calling predict on the model, or that you're reading the output incorrectly.

Comment: @adamconkey when ```result[0][0]``` is changed to ```result```, it simple outputs ```[[0]]``` instead of ```0```

Comment: As  `predict_classes` returns "A numpy array of class predictions", so your code was correct with `result[0][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem:

You generated a `test_set` with **scaling**:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('C:/Users/chill/PycharmProjects/499Actual/venv/data/TestDataSet/',
                                            target_size=(64, 64),
                                            batch_size=7,
                                            class_mode='binary')
```

But you never use it, you use an imported file from the test directory and use it without scaling:

```
test_image = image.load_img('C:/Users/chill/PycharmProjects/499Actual/venv/data/TestDataSet/Guns/301.jpeg',
                            target_size=(64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
```

That is why the predictor can not classify the **later** imported image correctly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm going to be combining this with some ideas from adamconkey and I'll keep you posted

Comment: @ConnerHill Welcome, sure I am looking forward to it. Meanwhile I'm checking the other code parts too for possible issue as well.

Comment: @ConnerHill you can simply get a good result, if you erase from `'C:/Users/chill/PycharmProjects/499Actual/venv/data/TestDataSet/'` all other samples except of 301.jpeg. then pass `test_set` to `classifier.predict_classes`

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! I’ll give that a try as well. I’ve also been looking at what you recommended about the scaling: since I had to scale (normalize) the test_set, how would you recommend going about making predictions on the entire set? 

In all reality, I won’t be testing only a single image once my code is working. I’ll be testing for accuracy over an entire set (test_set). I’ve been trying to do research on this but I’ve struggled to find a solution.

Comment: @ConnerHill Putting through the entire scaled test_set to `classifier.predict_classes` you will get the predictions.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll be on my machine here in a few minutes and I’ll try these adjustments. Will keep you posted. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Here is what I adjusted it to: ```result=classifier.predict_classes(test_set)
print(result)``` and now it appears to give me a prediction for each image in the set: ```[[0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]]```   Next, I'm going to increase the amount of training and see how these predictions match up.

Comment: @ConnerHill That's great, I'm wondering what willl be the final result.

Comment: Using your suggestions, I was able to finally get successful predictions and the program predicts from new images with an average accuracy of ~96%. Thank you for all of your help!